# Google Cloud Pub/Sub integration in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking for a standard way to integrate my iOS application with Google cloud Pub/Sub. After investing two days time of research on internet I did not find any direct way of implementation. Just wondering where to get started.

Comment: Google publishes the interface to Pub/Sub [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish). What problem are you having using it? There are many challenges in implementing Google Cloud Pub/Sub with external devices. The first is authorization. Pub/Sub requires OAuth. How are you going to authorize an iOS device to make authorized requests? My advice is to create a proxy (Cloud Run, Functions, etc) that interfaces to Pub/Sub on behalf of mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to publish/receive messages from Google Cloud Pub/Sub.

1. Make a call to the [Cloud Pub/Sub REST API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish).
   You'll be using your preferred iOS REST client SDK to handle the REST request and response. You do need to take care the REST API authentication as documented here. One drawback of connecting directly to the REST endpoint is that you end up embedding or parameterizing the GCP specific information such as GCP project and Pub/Sub topic information in your mobile app. Which could be some overhead when upgrading or release new mobile apps.
2. Use a gateway/proxy for Cloud Pub/Sub.
   The idea is to build a mobile backend that proxies Pub/Sub requests. The gateway implementation can be AppEngine, Cloud Run or GKE (Kubernetes). The flow looks something like following:

`iOS app -> GKE Pub/Sub Proxy -> Cloud Pub/Sub -> DataFlow (or other services)`

The proxy can handle some Cloud and Pub/Sub specific functions such as authentication, Pub/Sub message batching etc. Essentially offload them from the mobile app side, provide a better separation pattern.

Here is one example of [setting up Pub/Sub proxy on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/setting-up-a-pubsub-proxy-for-mobile-clients-on-gke?hl=en).